# AWS - the role defined for the function cannot be assumed by lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am new to AWS CDK and have run into an issue wwhen setting up my Lambda. Here is my code:

```
import { ManagedPolicy, Role, Group, User } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import { NodejsFunction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs';
import { LambdaIntegration } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';

 const group1 = new Group(this, 'group-1', {
      managedPolicies: [
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AdministratorAccess'),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonEC2FullAccess'),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('SecretsManagerReadWrite'),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('IAMFullAccess'),

        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonS3FullAccess'),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator'),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
          'AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess'
        ),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonRDSFullAccess'),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonSSMFullAccess'),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonCognitoPowerUser')
      ]
    });

    const group2 = new Group(this, 'group-2', {
      managedPolicies: [
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AWSCloudFormationFullAccess'),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AWSLambda_FullAccess')
      ]
    });

    const user = new User(this, 'root', {});

    group1.addUser(user);
    group2.addUser(user);

    const lambdaRole = new Role(this, 'lambdaRole', {
      roleName: 'lambdaRole',
      assumedBy: user
    });

const lambda = new LambdaIntegration(
  new NodejsFunction(this, 'statusFunction', {
    entry: 'lambda.js',
    functionName: 'lambda',
    role: lambdaRole,
  })
);
```

I have created some groups that contain a range of policies and I have attached a user to those two groups. I want to now use that user with all these permissions to execute a lambda function. My understanding is that in order to be able to do so I have to first create a role for the lambda which I have done. I then configure the `assumedBy` prop of the new role to be the user I just created with all the permissions - my understanding is that this should pass down all the permissions of the user to the role that will execute the lambda...

When I try deploy (via `cdk deploy`) I get the following error:

> the role defined for the function cannot be assumed by lambda

Why would this be?

Comment: Your Lambda function will be run by the AWS Lambda service, not by any user. See the [example trust policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html#permissions-executionrole-api). The Lambda service itself will need to be able to assume the IAM role.

Comment: Sorry but it's still unclear what I need to do? Can I add managed policy groups to a role like I do with a user? Would that even be the right approach?

Comment: This [article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-add-lambda-permission) might be helpful.

Comment: Its not really. My problem is that I can create groups for a user but not for a role... so I easily hit my max limit of 10 managed policies per role. Is there a way to make policy groups for roles?

Comment: Stepping back a second, your initial error was "the role defined for the function cannot be assumed by lambda" which afaik happens because your Lambda function's trust relationship does not allow `lambda.amazonaws.com` to assume the role. Your discussion of groups and users seems to be a misunderstanding - Lambda functions have no configuration related to IAM Users or Groups. The Lambda function simply has an IAM Role. I don't know what permissions your Lambda function needs in order to do its work, but it's vanishingly rare to see AdministratorAccess and numerous FullAccess policies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, you are likely correct about the FullAccess policies. Is there a way to get around the 10 managed policies limit on IAM roles without asking for a quota increase from AWS?

Comment: I would investigate the need to have so many managed policies before going a quota route. Your policy is perhaps over-permissioned. Also note that AdministratorAccess actually encompasses pretty much all AWS permissions so the other managed policies are redundant. That said, it's probably a mistake for your Lambda function to have AdministratorAccess and things like IAMFullAccess in the first place. Also, note that you can also attach an inline policy to the IAM role with the things you need spelled out, for example `"action": "s3:*"` without needing to go the managed policy route.

Comment: Thank you, what would be the downside to using a managed policy though? Are there limits to the amount of inline policies you cacn add?

Comment: You can read details of the various [quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html) but role inline policies can be up to 10,240 characters while a role may have a maximum of 10 managed policies (and that's a hard limit, not a soft limit, so you cannot raise it). Use whatever combination of inline policy and managed policies makes sense to you, within the available limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lambda's role needs to be assumable by the Lambda service principal, not by the user.

You may find it easier to not create the Lambda directly and instead let the NodejsFunction construct create the Role for you. Add any permissions your Lambda function needs by calling the .[addToRolePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html#addwbrtowbrrolewbrpolicystatement) function.

If you're trying to let your user invoke the function, then you need something like:

```
const lambdaFunction = new NodejsFunction(this, 'statusFunction', {
    entry: 'lambda.js',
    functionName: 'lambda',
    role: lambdaRole,
});

const lambda = new LambdaIntegration(
  lambdaFunction
);

group1.grantInvoke(lambdaFunction);
```